# Swift mac OS menubar style Bigsur

Tags: swift, macos, macos-big-sur, menubar

[image]

I would like to create a menu like style `Bigsur`, at the moment I am using `NSPopover`, but I would like to abandon this style.

What should I use to have such a `menubar`?

Comment: It's a menu bar extra extension. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/menu-bar-extras/ Here's a tutorial: https://8thlight.com/blog/casey-brant/2019/05/21/macos-menu-bar-extras.html

Comment: Ask not what `NSPopover` can do for you.  Ask what you can do for `NSStatusBar`.